# Greenplum's pg_dump cannot support lock statement

Tags: greenplum, pg-dump, hawq

I'm using `pg_dump` to backup and recreate a database's structure. To that end I'm calling `pg_dump -scf backup.sql` for the backup. But it fails with the following error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  Cannot support lock statement yet
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE my_schema.my_table IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

I couldn't find reference this particular error anywhere. Is it possible to get around this?

edit: for a little more context, I ran it in verbose mode, and this is what is displayed before the errors:

```
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like this is a Postgres database; the only search result for this error message is in the [Apache HAWQ source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq/blob/c21534a8800f1e0ba64868d3423c567efeb6b64c/src/backend/tcop/utility.c#L1677) (and it looks like they don't support `LOCK` yet).

Comment: @NickBarnes Here's what `SELECT version();` returns: "PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.0 build 1) (HAWQ 2.3.0.2 build 6675)"

Comment: @NickBarnes If the database does not support `LOCK` how could they be there in the database?

Comment: Added Greenplum tag, as this is greenplum related. Greenplum is **based** on Postgres.

Comment: As a side note: I remember having troubles with Greenplum and posting on greenplum user group on google. You might want to look there as well, it get's answered really fast.

Comment: What does `pg_dump --version` say? Sounds like you might be using a standard Postgres version of `pg_dump`. HAWQ appears to have [its own fork](https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq/tree/master/src/bin/pg_dump).

Comment: HAWQ is a fork of Greenplum which is a fork of PostgreSQL.  The tag for Greenplum should be removed.